# Java Applet GUI problem with components

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swing, applet

I'm having trouble with placing GUI components in an applet. I am looking for a way to place it using absolute coordinate and sizes. 
Here's what I've done:

```
public class app extends JApplet { 


public void init() {
    setSize(450,450);
    try {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Creation of swing components not finished");
    }


}

public void createGUI() {
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    menuFile.add(openItem);
    menubar.add(menuFile);
    setJMenuBar(menubar);


    app_buttons ab = new app_buttons();
    add(ab.button1);
    add(ab.button2);
    add(ab.button3);
}



}



public class app_buttons {
    public JButton button1;
    public JButton button2;
    public JButton button3;

    public apptextbox() {
       button1 = new JButton("1");
               button1.setBounds(20,20,20,20);
       button2 = new JButton("2");
               button2.setBounds(60,60,20,20);
       button3 = new JButton("3");
               button3.setBounds(90,90,20,20);

    }
 }
```

I can't figure out how to do it, either the components don't show or they fit the whole applet area. I want to specify for all my buttons, textareas, etc exactly how big they are and exactly where they will be placed. I've looked at tutorials on the web but it dosn't work, the components dont get displayed.

I don't want buttons, textareas, etc to resize either. Everything just static where I indicate them. For example when creating a JTextArea with (15,35) in size; it dosn't seem to matter because it resizes anyway.

Thanks

Comment: "I am looking for a way to place it using absolute coordinate and sizes."  That is where the problems will start, and plague the applet until fixed.  The fix is to use standard layouts to do the heavy lifting of positioning & sizing GUI elements at run-time.  See [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) in the Java Tutorial fro further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
setLayout(null);
```

for your applet in your `init()`.

Comment: That worked fine for buttons! However what do you do with JTextArea and JComboBoxes? I've tried setLocation but then the component isn't visible. If I use setBounds, the whole textarea isn't displayed unless I enter the exact parameters

Comment: If you use a null layout, then you are completely responsible for the size and locations of all components added to that container, so yes you will need to use setBounds or equivalent.  I suggest strongly that you avoid using null layout and exact positioning, but instead use multiple nested JPanels, each with their own appropriate layout manager.  Edit: I guess I'm stating what Andrew has already suggested above -- I second all his thoughts!